# subset of shapefile changes value when defined "as.numeric" in R

Tags: shapefile, r, polygon

In R, I have a shapefile with polygons. I subsetted by a secondary ID. Now, I want to sum up all area values of the subset.
These are the are values of the subset:

```
shapefile.subset$area
## 7767 1597 947  626  552 
## 1424 Levels: 0 1 10060 10070 10124 1013 1017 10175 1019 10191 1022 102361 
## 10237 10298 1030 10324 10327 1035 1039 10403 10405 1042 1044 104453 104533 
## 10508 1051 10562 ... 9982
```

Summing returns the following:

```
sum(shapefile.subset$area)
## Error in Summary.factor(c(1247L, 275L, 1388L, 1101L, 1025L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

So I tried to convert into numeric

```
as.numeric(shapefile.subset$area)
```

which returns

```
1247  275 1388 1101 1025
```

Thus five values that do not have anything in common with the original values. Note, that these also appear in the error message of `sum(shapefile.subset$area)`. I am really stuck here - how can I avoid this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not at all strange, the values being returned after coercion are the position in the factor and not the value in the vector. In a numeric vector that is, for some reason a factor, you coerce to a character then numeric ie, as.numeric(as.character(x))

Let's create a numeric vector of [0,1,5] and coerce to a factor.

```
class( x <- c(0,1,0,1,5,1) )
class( x <- as.factor(x) )
```

When we look a the factor levels you will see that the value "5" is in the third position of the factor. If we coerce straight to a numeric we will end up with [1,2,3] as the values. However, if we coerce to character first, then the values are the correct numeric values.

```
levels(x)
as.numeric(x)
as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

However, in your case the vector contains character values and cannot be coerced into a number. And, yes in looking at the error you do, in fact, have character values in this vector. You could use some of the string manipulation functions available in R but, I would suspect that since the data is an alpha-numeric identifier that, just the numeric portion is not unique.

If we introduce an alpha-numeric character into the vector, when we coerce into numeric R will return an NA coercion error and just drop the value. This is where it gets a bit dangerous using the stringsAsFactors=FALSE argument in readOGR. When you coerce you can end up with NA values that are not really NA values but rather a result of a field having some sort of non-numeric value.

```
(x <- as.factor(c("1","2","3","5","6L")))
as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

It is not entirely clear in your question but if you are wanting to sum a numeric vector based on each value in a aggregate (summary) vector. This can easily be done using tapply. In this way you can avoid sub-setting data just to get aggregate statistics.

```
( x <- c(rep(1,10),rep(20,10)) ) 
( y <- runif(20) )
tapply(y, x, sum)
```

If you are just after the total area of the polygons, you could sidestep this entirely and just use gArea in the rgeos package. The byid=TRUE argument will result in area(s) for each polygon.

***Update, it just occurred to me that a GIS software could be storing large numbers using scientific notation. I would imagine that this would be parsed as a character thus, resulting in a factor in R. If this is the case, these values would be erroneous when coerced. It sounds like it would be best to just get areas in R and not rely on an existing field in the data. If this is the case, and one needs a field in the data, you may have to deal with this in the software that created the data.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar error just couple of days ago after I upgraded various R stuff.

*If you're confident you can assume the field has no characters* you can add stringsAsFactors=FALSE to your readOGR statement. 
Eg.

`df<- readOGR("C:/file.shp",layer = "file", verbose = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Then run as.numeric() on the area field. It would be worth understanding why the field has not been read correctly (possibly it's a 64 bit integer in the file).

Comment: Without understanding what is going on under the hood here, this is dangerious advice and very well could prodece erroneous results on numeric fields that may contain character values.

Comment: fair enough. I've updated it

Comment: No, it would not be due to a 64-int value. The only reason would be a character value somewhere in the field. If you look closely at your results I would bet that those values ended up as NA. I guess it is possible that a GIS software is introducing an odd nodata value or field definition that GDAL does not recognize but, that is unlikely.

Comment: Oh, it could also be attributed to a GIS software using scientific notation for large numbers. This could very well be parsed as a character.